# Python and PostgreSQL - Check on multi-insert operation

Tags: python, postgresql

I'll make it easier on you.

I need to perform a multi-insert operation using parameters from a text file.
However, I need to report each input line in a log or an err file depending on the insert status.

I was to able to understand if the insert was ok or nor when performing it once at a time (for example, using cur.rowcount or simply a try..except statement).

Is there a way to perform N insert (corresponding to N input line) and to understand which fail?

Here my code:

```
QUERY="insert into table (field1, field2, field3) values (%s, %s, %s)"
```

Let

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

be 3 rows from input file. So

```
args=[('a','b','c'), ('d','e','f'),('g','h','i')]
cur.executemany(QUERY,args)
```

Now, let's suppose only the first 2 rows were successfully added. So I have to track such a situation as follows:

**log file**

```
a b c
d e f
```

**err file**

```
g h i
```

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
QUERY="insert into table (field1, field2, field3) values ({}, {}, {})"


with open('input.txt', 'r') as inputfile:
    readfile = inputfile.read()
    inputlist = readfile.splitlines()
    listafinal = []
    for x in inputlist:
        intermediate = x.split(' ')
        cur.execute(QUERY.format(intermediate[0], intermediate[1], intermediate[2]))
        # if error:
        #     log into the error file
        # else:
        #     log into the success file
```

**Do not forget to undo the comments and ajust the error as you like**

Answer (score 0):

How common do you expect failures to be, and what kind of failures? What I have done in such similar cases is insert 10,000 rows at a time, and if the chunk fails then go back and do that chunk 1 row at a time to get the full error message and specific row.  Of course, that depends on failures being rare.  What I would be more likely to do today is just turn off synchronous_commit and process them one row at a time always.